# Why is element scope null in directive unit test?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I have created a custom directive that has a watch for a couple of isolated scope properties, here is the relevant code:

```
 scope.$watchGroup(['repairer', 'initial'], function () {

           scope.Repairer = null;
...

           scriptingService.getScript(request).then(function (scripts) {
                            scope.scripts = scripts;
                        });
```

I wrote a couple of test but none of them work,this is one of them:

```
it('should  Repairer be 2', function() {

    scope.$apply(function() {
      scope.initial = 2;
    });

    expect(element.isolateScope().Repairer).toEqual(2);

  });
```

But I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Repairer' of undefined
```

How can I make the tests work? Looks like the directive is somehow not running in the test.

Here is a plunkerref:http://plnkr.co/edit/0R6KXp86BXFzhPRhT98S?p=preview

Comment: i've spotted a smal error in your code (declared $scope, but used scope), but for some reason you link function isn't called at all.

Answer (score 0):

Problems:
1. you try to $compile your scope, to an elemet whicht has no html, since your template is ' '.
(you've mocked it with $httpBackend).

```
 // templateUrl: 'components/directives/scripting/scripting.html',
```

2. you need to mock your service for every test:

   ```
   spyOn(scriptingService, "getScript").andReturn(qq.when({}))
   ```
3. you had a syntax error (declared $scope, but used scope):

   link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

   ```
           var visibleScript = 0;
           scope.isHidden = false;

           scope.$watchGroup(['repairer', 'initial'], function () {
   ```

   ...

Check this out:

http://plnkr.co/edit/AnqBx4Z6PuRXElwXA1Bm?p=preview

Comment: Hi Ron, I uncommented the templateUrl bit in the directive it was supposed to be on :) but now i am getting an error:
cannot read property Repairer of undefined. I thought I mocked out the template with the WhenGet statement in the test?

Comment: btw Ron I am curious how you debug errors with karmine jasmine? I find it hard to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: i'm a bit old fashoined.. i insert a lot of console.log() and see what code is running...